# Best way to "save" a value in a textbox (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, session, save

I have a textbox where the user enters some data and saves this value to the database. Next time the user comes to the same aspx page in the same session, the value should be restored in the textbox. Whats the best way to do this? Using the session maybe?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is a good way to save the data.  You also should have a way to load the data from the database if the session is not available. (ie, they come to the same page the next day)

something like this:

```
public string MyVariable
{
   get
   {
       if (Session["MyVariable"] == null)
       {
           Session["MyVariable"] = LoadFromDatabase();
       }

       return Session["MyVariable"];
   }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyTextBox.Text = MyVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the session, you will be able to do it only within a session unless you maintain a session in state server or in database.

For the first time, store the user entered text into the session and also update it in the Database. Later, whenever you need to show this value to the user, check whether the textbox value exits in the session. If not, then read it from the database, update the session with the value and show it to the user.

Comment: Thats not a problem, I only need to do it during the session.